# Add values to an array while looping through

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am looking for a way to add values to an array while I am looping through. This might sound a bit confusing but the following example will show what I want to do.

```
// Create a test array
$rows = range('a', 'z');

// Loop through the test array
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    print $key . ': '.$row."\n";
    if (false === strpos($key, 'added') && $row == 'd') {
        // Add value to test array
        $rows['added_'.$key] = $row;
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
4: e
5: f
6: g
7: h
8: i
9: j
10: k
11: l
12: m
13: n
14: o
15: p
16: q
17: r
18: s
19: t
20: u
21: v
22: w
23: x
24: y
25: z
```

However, the `foreach` loop will not output the added values.

Comment: Works totally fine for me...  print_r($rows) displays the data array

Comment: Are you expecting to see the output `$key : $row` where `$row` is the updated?

Comment: @HarveyFletcher Yes. I would like it to output `['added_'.$key]` as well.

Comment: Last element of $rows:   `[added_3] => d )`

Comment: Move your `print` statement to be after your `if(){}` statement

Comment: @clearshot66 You are right. The problem is that that value won't be looped.